# MongoDB Shell - Print the first element of an array

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use the function print in "NoSQL Manager for MongoDB 4.9.10.2" to print the first element of an array. I'm trying to do the following:

```
    var start = ISODate("2018-12-18T03:00:00.000Z"); 
var end = ISODate("2018-12-19T02:59:59.000Z"); 

db.moicaTickets.aggregate([

    { $match : 
        { asunto:{$exists:true},
          asunto: {$ne:null},
          tiempos:{$exists:true}, 
          tiempos: {$ne:null},
          problemas:{$exists:true},
          creado:{$exists:true}, 
          "creado.lastEvent_tc": { $gt: start, $lt: end } }},
    { $project: 
        { pFecha: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$creado.lastEvent_tc", timezone: "-03:00" } }, 
        asunto: 1, 
        tiempos: 1, 
        nroTkt: 1,
        losProblemas: { $arrayElemAt: ["$problemas",0]},
        primerProblema: "$losProblemas.nombre",
        primera: { $arrayElemAt: ["$tiempos",0]}}},
    { $addFields: { "lacola":{ "$toObjectId": "$primera.cola" }}},
    { $lookup:
       {
         from: "moicaTicketsColas",
         localField: "lacola",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "nombreCola"
         }}

         ]).forEach(function(doc){
         print(doc.nroTkt+";"+doc.nombreCola.0.arbol+";"+doc.pFecha+";"+doc.asunto.titulo+";"+doc.primerProblema);
})
```

But i get the next error:

```
2018-12-19T12:00:06.660-0300 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list @(shell):29:44
```

Comment: show all  QUERY .

Comment: I added the whole query. Thanks!

Comment: This is an example of "nombreCola":

"nombreCola" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b55f8a351b9979f1e417b43"),
            "nombre" : "Al. Fuentes",
            "padre" : "5ad8a36251b99792eb60418a",
            "nivel" : 2,
            "creado" : {
                "creador" : "gerodriguez",
                "lastEvent_st" : "23-07-2018 12:47:47",
                "lastEvent_ts" : 1532360867,
                "lastEvent_tc" : ISODate("2018-07-23T15:47:47.377Z")
            },
            "arbol" : "Ceop - Noc - Al. Fuentes"
        }
    ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, what goes outside the query is JavaScript, so the proper way to print an array (or in this case, get the first element) is:

```
print(doc.nroTkt+";"+doc.nombreCola[0].arbol+";"+doc.pFecha+";"+doc.asunto.titulo+";"+doc.primerProblema);
```

Thank you!